# Can someone suggest a nice engineering application of a second order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, applications

I am writing a case for one of applied mathematics course involving solving differential equations.  Can someone suggest an engineering application of a practical problem that I can ask my students to come up with a solution.  Should not be as heavy as a heat equation nor should it be as easy of a simple first order differential equation.  I am looking for moderate complexity.  Even if someone suggests references that will be great.

Comment: Vibrating string?  LRC circuit?

Comment: Thanks could you refer me to some material.

Comment: @SatishRamanathan: http://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS%20Concepts%20and%20Contexts/upfiles/3c3-AppsOf2ndOrders_Stu.pdf, https://www.engr.sjsu.edu/trhsu/Chapter%204%20Second%20order%20DEs.pdf

Comment: Thanks @Moo. Will be grateful for this assistance. Thanks guys!!

Comment: Aslo see: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.133.8760&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Forced and damped harmonic motion, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to point you to a great pdf that I found only recently that has exactly what you ask:

http://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS%20Concepts%20and%20Contexts/upfiles/3c3-AppsOf2ndOrders_Stu.pdf